# SQL query how to find the average number of rental books for each quarter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the average number of rental books for each quarter.

```
Rental(RegNum, DateBorrowed, DateReturned)
Books(RegNum, BookName, Category)
```

What i am trying is

```
SELECT QUARTER(DateBorrowed) AS Quarter, COUNT(RegNo) As QuarterAvgRentalNum
FROM Rental
GROUP BY QUARTER(DateBorrowed);
```

However, I keep getting the Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You may simply need to add to the `GROUP BY`: `GROUP BY QUARTER(DateBorrowed), RegNo;` ?

Comment: What `mysql`version do you use? In 8.0 your proposed SQL seems to run successfully, the DBFiddle says : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d101683016b20e1d1daee3d9c23830af

Comment: @PaulT. Add RegNo in the GroupBy. Got the same error.

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I'm using mysql 8.0

Comment: Okay, when the DbFiddle environment is not buggy, I'm not sure what the reason for yours failing might be, see also the proposed Answer

Comment: Can you modify your Question if there is something wrong with the previously linked DbFiddle repro attempt, or a different way to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @StefanWuebbe I'm using mysql 8.0 –
> Amber

In `MySql` 8.0 the exact `SQL` statement you proposed seems to run successfully:

```sql
Create Table Rental (DateBorrowed Date, regNo Int);
  
SELECT QUARTER(DateBorrowed) AS Quarter, COUNT(RegNo) As QuarterAvgRentalNum
    FROM Rental
    GROUP BY QUARTER(DateBorrowed);
```

... tested in: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f96c6c1469bcb4c6ff5791cf814edf7a

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I ran the same code as before and now it works. I don't know why it didn't work before